# create a folder and folder inside it but getting a PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python

I am trying to create a folder and a folder inside it but Permission is denied everytime not matter what mode I use (tried 0o777, 0o770 etc.). I am working inside a Docker container if that matters.

This is my code:

```
for tenant in get_tenants:         
    os.chdir(conf_path)
    for file_fn in glob.glob("*.conf"):
        file = (file_fn.rsplit(".", 1)[0].split("-"))[0].upper()
        if file == tenant["name"]:
            with open(file_fn, 'r') as f:
                contents = f.read()
                job_name = re.search(r'Jobs = (.*)', contents).group(1)
                mkdir_with_mode(f"/var/lib/connects/state/{tenant}/{job_name}", 0o777)
```

I have tried to unmask as seen in similar examples but it didn't help:

```
def mkdir_with_mode(directory, mode):
  if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    oldmask = os.umask(000)
    os.makedirs(directory, mode)
    os.umask(oldmask)
```

Any ideas? Thank you for your help!

Comment: There's a problem with directory permissions, I don't know what to tell you.  Hardly anything to do with the code.

Comment: `/var/lib/` usually requires root access.

Comment: I read that somewhere. Is there a possibility to give root access inside a python file?

Comment: Usually, if you're going to run a service with with a subdirectory in `/var/lib/`, you would create a user for that service and the subdirectory, then `chown` it for the new user.